# Required is not define

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Tengo creado el siguiente Schema,

```
const cardSchema    =    new Schema({

    description : {type :   String, required},
    color       : {type :   Number, required,default: 0}   
});

module.exports = mongoose.model( 'Card' , cardSchema);
```

El problema es que al iniciar el servidor me sale el siguiente  mensaje de error:

> ReferenceError: required is not defined in description : {type :   String, required}

Answer (score 1):

El problema viene de que node interpreta el required como si fuese una variable para después expandirla, que es el comportamiento normal de un objeto.

```js
let required = "Valor expandido"

let Schema = {
  description: {
    type: String,
    required
  },
  color: {
    type: Number,
    required,
    default: 0
  }
}

console.log(Schema)
```

Es necesario definir el valor como `{required:true}` para que se interprete como la propiedad de mongoose `required`.

Answer (score 0):

He analizo nuevamente el código y debería ser funcional, simplemente agrégale la condición true y revisa la estructuración de los espacios que no sea mal interpretado el código.

Algo así debería ser.

```
const cardSchema = new Schema({
  description: { type: String, required: true},
  color: { type: Number, require: true, default: 0}   
});
```

Comment: Cierto, rectifico son igual de validos en ese caso será la estructuración de los espacios... no veo ningún otro error.